# Killing the correct ArcMap process from Windows task manager

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, windows

I have 3 ArcMaps opened, one of them has a process which is taking a long time but still running. Another one hangs and I can't close it.

I want to kill the hung process, but how do I know from the task manager which one it is? I don't want to kill the one which has the long running process.

Comment: Are you trying to kill the process through the Applications or Processes tab in the task manager? You should be able to see how much memory and CPU is being used with each application in the Processes tab.

Comment: from task manager, but the problem the hanged is still using the CPU as well the one which has the process

Comment: I've been there before! It's like Russian roulette, and I lose every single time.

Answer (score 4):

As @Aaron mentioned, you could look in task manager to see which one is hung. Each instance of ArcMap should be its own app with unique `PID`. If your maps have different names (so not multiple copies of `Untitled - Arcmap`), you can expand the running apps and view the names there.

This is different from other applications (`Firefox`, I'm looking at you) that run separate windows/tabs all in a single process.

[image]

If that doesn't work for you, or you want a more automated approach, `PowerShell` works great:

```
gps arcmap | % {if (!($_.Responding)) {$_.Kill()}}
```

script version:

```
Get-Process -Name ArcMap | ForEach-Object {if ($_.Responding -eq $false) {$_.Kill()}}
```

Essentially, get all processes with the name `ArcMap` and loop through each one, killing it if it's locked up (i.e., not responding).

Per the comments with @ian, the Task Manager approach might only work on Windows 8/10. PowerShell is included with Windows 7 though, and so the syntax should work there.

Comment: The problem I've encountered is that just because it's hung doesn't mean it's Not responding.

Comment: @ian, what do you mean by that? To me, `hung == Not Responding` which is when the UI of an app goes opaque, you get the loading symbol, and the OS views the app as `Not Responding`.

Comment: Yeah, I would normally think that too, but I've had many occasions where ArcMap hangs and doesn't give the Not responding message - which makes knowing which process to kill very difficult.

Comment: @ian, how do you know it's hung then? *cheeky grin* In all seriousness, plenty different app's UI won't always show that it's `Not Responding` (nor will task manager all the time unless the refresh is high). Whenever an app is thinking/loading and not allowing the UI state to be changed, it's technically "Not Responding" to input (not what it means, I know).

Comment: Honestly, it hasn't happened in awhile, but I've definitely been in the same spot as OP. It would have been on Windows 7 though, which didn't have the fancy task manager in your picture. So, I like the idea of expanding the running apps to see the MXD name, but I more than likely always had Untitled as the name (I can't remember if Windows 7 listed the MXD name or not).  I've also never tried the Powershell example. But this brought back memories of doing eenie meenie miney mo, and ALWAYS picking the wrong one!

Comment: @ian, ahh yeah, forgot that task manager was drastically overhauled at Windows 8. It's a lot nicer now, as you can see. And yes, I'm no stranger to killing the incorrect process in Windows XP/7. ;)

Comment: @ian There's also the reverse possibility that I've seen frequently enough: Windows identifies ArcMap as "Not Responding," but it is processing anyway. (My best guess is poor programming where the processing is happening on the GUI thread instead of in the background.)